# Does a series in Japan only get aired if it has more than 13 episodes?

Tags: anime-history

while reading [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4067/1587) it said in one of the quotes

> After the first season of Beast Wars (comprising 26 episodes) aired in Japan, the Japanese were faced with a problem. The second Canadian season was only 13 episodes long, not enough to warrant airing on Japanese TV.

however i have a number of series which don't have even 20 episodes like *Puella Magi Madoka Magica* (12 episodes), *Black Rock Shooter (Series)* (8 Episodes), *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha* (the original series and A's, 13 episodes each) and a number of *Monogatari* series have less than 10 episodes

So i am wondering if what the quote says is accurate and if so how does a series, like the ones i mention, get aired on TV if they aren't long enough to warrant airing on Japanese TV?

Comment: [closely related](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/22479/1458). Pre-90's they were a lot stricter in series lengths.

Comment: I'll be honest - looking at the [original Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers#Beast_Wars_and_Beast_Machines_.281996.E2.80.932000.29) and where the reference comes from, I'd slap a huge [citation needed] sticker on that bit.

Answer (score 3):

No, 13 episodes are enough.

[Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%93%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA_%E8%B6%85%E7%94%9F%E5%91%BD%E4%BD%93%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC) in Japanese have different note for it:

> 加えて、この作品と『メタルス』は元々は1つの作品だったが、当時海外では『メタルス』が展開中で日本放送が間に合わなかった。その為、本作（『メタルス』と『リターンズ』を含む）の未来に当たり、日本オリジナルの『ビーストウォーズII』と『ビーストウォーズネオ』を挟み放送することとなった。その為、最終回放送直後、抗議の電話が殺到した。

Translate:

> Originally this anime (Season1) and "Metals" (Season2) are same series. but at the time Season1 finished in Japan, "Metals" is not created yet. then, they create and aired original seasons called "Beast wars2" and "Beast wars neo" before "Metals". Many user complain it.

Based on aired date table in [wikipeida](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%93%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA_%E8%B6%85%E7%94%9F%E5%91%BD%E4%BD%93%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC),
It's always aired weekly in Japan but not in US.
Episode 1 in Season 1 is aired 9/16/1996 in US, and 10/1/1997 in Japan.
But Episode 26 is aired 4/1/1997 in US, and 3/25/1997 in Japan.
Japan side needs more episode for 4/8/1997.